# failed_attempts not increment, Devise Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems

I have Ajax login with Devise with overridden controller `Sessions` and method `create`:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

    def create
        resource = User.find_for_database_authentication(email: params[:user][:email])

        unless resource
            render json: 0
        end
        if resource.valid_password?(params[:user][:password])
            sign_in :user, resource
            return render json: 1
        end
    end
end
```

Login works fine, but If I try with wrong password, it not increment column `failed_attempts`.

I have `:lockable` in the model `User` and all the columns in the table.
Failed attempts works fine without override the class `Sessions`.

I know, I need to use some method or override `find_for_database_authentication` method, but I don't know what is the name of this method.

Comment: try `resource.active_for_authentication?` instead of `valid_password?`

Comment: It returns every time 1 (success login), even if the password is wrong. May be I am doing something wrong. Should I pass the password `params[:user][:password]` somewhere ?

Comment: Take a look at this https://github.com/thanhluanuit/devise_ajax_example/tree/authenticate_ajax I think the code in your controller should call warden.

Comment: my bad. `active_for_authentication?` is called after authentication. Should use '#valid_for_authentication?` instead.

Comment: Same, logging with invalid password.

Comment: The code from GutHub works fine `if warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#failure")`, Thanks :).

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
if resource.valid_for_authentication?{resource.valid_password?(params[:user][:password])}
```